# Using curl command in Windows prompt how to execute multi line command?

Tags: windows, curl, cmd

We're attempting to run the following multi-line curl command in a Windows CMD window:

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Token <SERVER_TOKEN>' \
 -H 'Accept-Language: en_US' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 'https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price?start_latitude=37.7752315&start_longitude=-122.418075&end_latitude=37.7752415&end_longitude=-122.518075'
```

When doing so, it appears to be treating each line of code separately.

[image]
Is there a way to pass a multi-line curl command in a Windows CMD window?

Comment: Backslash is used to escape or quote (some) things in Unix shells, and C, C++, other C-based (including awk) and Java programs, not in CMD. CMD allows quoting some things, including end-of-line, with **`^` uparrow; use that**.

Comment: Its called a caret ^. 0x2191 is the up arrow ↑.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Here is all their names Acute Accent  (`´`), Breve  (`˘`), Caron  (`ˇ`), Cedilla  (`¸`), Circumflex  (`ˆ`), Diæresis / Umlaut   (`¨`), Dialytika Tonos  (`΅`), Dot Above  (`˙`), Dot Below  (`̣`), Double Acute Accent  (`˝`), Grave Accent  (```), Hook Above  (`̉̉`), Macron  (`ˉ`), Ring Above  (`˚`), Tilde  (`˜`), Tonos  (`΄`), `).

Comment: This is the list for European languages **and** Vietnamese as they have your standard 5 vowels but with 6 modifiers = 30 vowels. The French gave them their written language.

Comment: @catcat: to someone who grew up with Teletype models 33 and 35, 0x5E will always be uparrow, but I'm willing to compromise on [hat](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/A/ASCII.html). It is definitely not caret; caret is _under_ the baseline, not above x-height, and is U+2038 in Unicode but not in usual 'DOS' codepages at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```
curl "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/estimates/price?start_latitude=37.7752315&start_longitude=-122.418075&end_latitude=37.7752415&end_longitude=-122.518075" -H "Authorization: Token YNjXGKdc8AcnPGzGf-qFm2eFKGeG6RpOHLLgXLH-" -H "Accept-Language: en_US" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Apparently, needed double quotes, not single quotes.